# missing required icon issue and marketing icon not found issue

Tags: ios, xcode9

I just updated Xcode from version 8.3 to 9 via appstore. I am trying to submit my new app version but I am facing app upload problem with Xcode 9.
I had not got this issue before when I uploaded app using Xcode 8.3. My app is iPhone app and minimum target is iOS 9. My code is in Swift 3.2.
The issue is about the missing required icon as shown below:

[image]

When I upload app with Application Loader 3.0, it gives me error saying "Missing required icon file........ >=7.0" and about marketing icon 1024x1024 in .png without alpha channel and transparency. I have followed all those criteria.

[image]

I have all the icons including 120 X 120 and also marketing icon of 1024 X 1024 included
I have all the app icons in Assets.xcassets folder in AppIcon.

[image]

Even then I and getting same error again and again have not been able to upload the new version of app to iTunes.

I googled and checked most of the stacker flow posts regarding this type of issue.But I am still not able to get rid of this issue.
Its been 2 days I am trying this.
I also tried without using asset catalog and adding app icons in the App bundle in folder with name format as icon.png and so on.

I then added the app icon names in info.plist as well and tried, but also the error is same and is not letting me to upload the app to appstore.

[image]

I am not sure what is the issue. Is this the bug in Xcode 9 or is there any mistake I need to correct. I have uploaded app many times but this is the first time I am getting the issue. Not sure what to do. Anybody faced this issue recently? Any help would be highly acknowledged. Thanks.

Comment: Same problem... help!!!

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem. Check this: [solution](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7003)

Just add this code below to your podfile:

```
post_install do |installer|
      installer.aggregate_targets.each do |target|
        copy_pods_resources_path = "Pods/Target Support Files/#{target.name}/#{target.name}-resources.sh"
        string_to_replace = '--compile "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}"'
        assets_compile_with_app_icon_arguments = '--compile "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}" --app-icon "${ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME}" --output-partial-info-plist "${BUILD_DIR}/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist"'
        text = File.read(copy_pods_resources_path)
        new_contents = text.gsub(string_to_replace, assets_compile_with_app_icon_arguments)
        File.open(copy_pods_resources_path, "w") {|file| file.puts new_contents }
      end
    end
```

and then run in console `pod install`

Comment: Got this error: `[!] An error occurred while processing the post-install hook of the Podfile.

No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-IconTest/Pods-IconTest-resources.sh`

Comment: Still getting the same error. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Whats the best way to share it with you? Looks pretty bad as a comment

Comment: Past it in your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155485/discussion-between-kathan-and-danielq).

Comment: Will do, and vice versa

Comment: Yes i also copied and pasted the above code by @DanielQ to my pod file and installed pod again and uploaded app, but still same issue... No luck at all.... :((

Comment: might be on to something

Answer (score 2):

After trying multiple things - getting rid of the alpha channel, messing with my pods, etc - turns out it was a High Sierra issue. A bit hacky, but basically have to make Xcode think you are on a lower OS.

See Stubyte`s answer on [this thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/86290).

What I did:

Locate your app's .xcarchive file, right click >> show package contents, navigate to products >> applications >> your application's name >> show package contents. Locate the info plist from here, and change the `BuildMachineOsBuild` to `16A323`. Then, submit the app.

Comment: Yes, @Kathan i also did same and it seems to work for me as well. App was uploaded, however the issue warning saying marketing app icon is required was still showing even I have added the marketing icon of 1024 X 1024. But even with this message, app upload process was proceeded.

Comment: same here, did you find a workaround/fix to the "missing marketing icon" warning ?

Comment: Successfully submitted, check the latest comments in [this thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/86290)